# Changing Property Of an object in a list affects the values in parent list. How to solve it?

Tags: java, java-8

```
List<Employee> unique=employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toCollection(()-> 
            new TreeSet<>Comparator.comparing(Employee::getIdentifier))), 
            ArrayList::new));

unique.stream()
        .forEach(employee->employee.setQuantity(0L));
```

Here changing the value in `unique` changes the value in `employees` also. How to resolve that?

Comment: You're mutating the state of the containing object, not the `List` itself. Solution would be copying/cloning these objects.

Comment: I think you forgot a left parenthesis somewhere...

Comment: @Flown Cloning means

Comment: Cloning means copying.

Comment: You don't need to collect your stream to a `TreeSet` to sort it. Just do `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(OrderItemInput::getIdentifier)).collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: If we do like this only the sorting takes place. I want to eliminate the duplicate objects with same Id.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: Now it is like. lets say, employees list contains A at 1000, B at 1001, again A at 1002 and B at 1003. My code will create a list named unique but points to first occurence of A and B. ie.  unique contains A at 1000 and B at 1001. So if I change property of A in unique it affects in employees as well...

Comment: As said by others, there is only one `Employee` object A, even if it is contained in (referenced by) two lists. It doesn’t matter which list you use to modify this object. If you make a copy of each object and store these copies into the second list, you can make changes to the copy which are not reflected by the original object. However, what’s the real life use case? There is only one `Employee` A; what’s the point of having the same employee with different properties?

Comment: Could you please add the class definition of Employee to your question? To me it looks like a design flaw, since ``quantity`` should not be an instance property of Employee in the first place.